# Rpush notification fails to deliver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to Rails. I am trying to send push notification using [rpush](https://github.com/rpush/rpush) gem.

I am following these steps:

```
n = Rpush::Gcm::Notification.new
n.app = Rpush::Gcm::App.find_by_name("android_app")
n.registration_ids = ["#{d.device_token}"]
n.data = { title: "#{self.title}"}
n.save!
```

The notification gets saved but is not getting delivered, and I get the following error description:

```
"Unable to deliver notification 10, received error (Failed to deliver to all recipients. Errors: NotRegistered.)"
```

Not able to understand the issue here. Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Based from this [forum](https://github.com/rpush/rpush/issues/96), maybe you have an invalid device registration ID in your system. This message indicates that the notification did not go through, so you must have another registration id that is valid for the notification that is going through. You may check this given link for more possible workarounds. Also make sure that you [device_token](https://github.com/rpush/rpush/issues/27) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

When you find above mentioned message in your log, means, as said @abielita and [rpush wiki](https://github.com/rpush/rpush/wiki/Delivery-Failures-&-Retries) documentation, the identification_id  GCM is using to send notification, *is no more valid*.

Device with (**d.device_token**) as registration token, is no more registered on GCM (Firebase) Service.

This message come for a specified reason: adapt your code to this condition.

Maybe is better destroy your "**d**" record !?

Becomes helpful **Rpush.reflect** in *config/initializers/rpush.rb*

Uncomment event notification **on.gcm_invalid_registration_id** and add your code inside block
e.g.

```
on.gcm_invalid_registration_id do |app, error, registration_id|
  Device.where(registration_id: registration_id).take.destroy
end
```

and encloses your sending notification code inside a conditional check

```
unless(d.nil?)
  n = Rpush::Gcm::Notification.new
  n.app = Rpush::Gcm::App.find_by_name("android_app")
  n.registration_ids = ["#{d.device_token}"]
  n.data = { title: "#{self.title}"}
  n.save!
end
```

I hope it help